# Remove Json object from json array element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var jsonArray = ["test", "test1", "test2"];
var matchedValue = "test1";
```

**I want to remove remove and (matchedValue) from the JsonArray.
 How can i delete and return rest of the string**

```
Expected output : ["test", "test2"];
```

**What I am doing :**

```
var setValue = JSON.parse(fetchMethodJsonArray);
dataRemoved = setValue.filter(function(el) {
              return el != fetchValue;
          });
```

It is not working

Please tell me the solution Thanks in advance.

Comment: [JSON](http://json.org/) is always a string. if not you do not have a JSON.

Comment: Your code looks okay, check if `fetchValue` has data. `setValue` is an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
// Assuming this is your fetched data
const fetchMethodJsonArray = [{
  "val": "One"
}, {
  "val": "Two"
}, {
  "val": "Three"
}];


var setValue = fetchMethodJsonArray;
const dataRemoved = setValue.filter((el) => {
  return el.val !== "One";
});

console.log(dataRemoved);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from what i got..

`jsonArray.splice(jsonArray.indexOf('string_to_search'));`

It will delete the found item and return remaining array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
const deleteObj = (data, column, search) => {
    let result = data.filter(m => m[column] !== search);

    return result;
}
```

When you want to remove an object from JSON array element use this method:

```js
const deleteObj = (data, column, search) => {
  let result = data.filter(m => m[column] !== search);

  return result;
}

const arr = [
  {
    name: 'test',
    surname: 'test1'
  },
  {
    name: 'test23',
    surname: 'newsname'
  },
  {
    name: 'test23',
    surname: 'newsname'
  }
]


const deleted = deleteObj(arr, 'name', 'test');
console.log(deleted);
```

In this sample, you will use filter method. Mozilla says about filter:

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented by the provided function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NodeJs, You can use 'modernarray' which is an small and simple npm package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/modernarray

Install it by `npm install modernarray`

```
let modernarray = require('modernarray');
let myarray = [{
  "val": "One"
}, {
  "val": "Two"
}, {
  "val": "Three"
}];
let outputArray2 = modernarray.popByValue(myarray,{val:"One"})
console.log(outputArray2)
```

Comment: Is this can be used in Vue.js?